# How do you see the name of the current package in GoLand?

Tags: go, goland

Without having to scroll to the top of the page, is there a way to see the name of the current package in GoLand?

The fastest I can do is (using Vi keys) typing `magg` (create mark `a`, go to top) then `` `a `` to get back. It's not bad, but ideally I want it to be visible at all times.

There's a top bar that shows some terse contextual information. Maybe there's a way to configure it? I haven't worked out how.

The Structure pane only lists symbols, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the `Quick Documentation` feature, via Ctrl + Q on Windows/Linux or F1 on macOS, on any identifier defined in the package and the first line of the output will be the name of the package it's defined in.

This is an example of how this would look like:

[image: Quick Documentation]

Another option would be to invoke the `Navigation Bar`, via Alt + Home on Windows/Linux or Cmd (⌘) + Up on macOS, and that would show you the path to the directory in which the package is contained, see below:

[image: Jump to Navigation Bar]

Comment: That only works for symbols you want to look up, not the package of the current file. Also the the directory name does not necessarily need to match the package name.

Comment: The symbols _are_ defined in the current file, which is in the current package, so this does work. A better question would be: Why do you need this feature? What's the use-case for it?

Comment: Are you saying I have to find a symbol that is in the local package, then use quick documentation?

Comment: As I said, if you can explain why you need this, then perhaps I can suggest a different way to do it.

Comment: A use-case for it: I'm working in a project with many packages, where the filenames are not all unique, and I want to see what package my current file is in, without navigating to the top and back.